# Convert arrays to one line in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, image

I have a problem with arrays in my PHP code. i'm trying to add colors from image to MySQL database.

This is a PHP:

```
$image = isset( $_GET['image'] ) ? $_GET['image'] : null;

$colors_of_image = new ColorsOfImage( $image );
$colors = $colors_of_image->getProminentColors();
```

Now the problem. with print_r result will be like this:

```
print_r($colors);
//Results
Array ( [0] => #996633 [1] => #999999 [2] => #424153 [3] => #E7D8B1 [4] => #663300 [5] => #FFFFFF [6] => #000000 [7] => #999900 [8] => #FF9900 [9] => #666600 [10] => #FFCC33 [11] => #CC6633 [12] => #660000 )
```

I need to convert these arrays to the one line and after that, add the result to MySQL. result should be like this:

```
#996633 #999999 #424153 #E7D8B1 #E7D8B1 #663300 #FFFFFF ...
```

And the MySQL part:

```
$db->query("
INSERT INTO
 colors (photo_id, color) 
 VALUES('{$PhotoID}', '{$image_colors}')
");
```

how i can convert all that colors arrays to the one regular string and add that string to database?

Comment: Please, **please**, be absolutely certain those values `$PhotoID` and `$image_colors` are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you're using PDO, the placeholder facility can take care of escaping for you automatically. Using string interpolation or concatenation is almost always a sign you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$image_colors = implode(' ', $colors);
```

FYI, that's probably not the best way to store that data.